# How add a variable from buffer selections?

Tags: qgis, buffer, fields-attributes

New to QGIS; don't know how to use commands. Here is my question!

1. I use a polygon layer of forest fires in Canada (N=50 000+)
2. I have a point layer of centroids of specific municipalities in Canada relevant for the research (N=145)
3. I buffered and selected all the fires located whitin a 75km radius from these municipalities, and created a new forest fire layer (Fires_Buffer_75km; N=4905)

Now, for each of these fire polygons selected, I want to add a new variable: the NAME of the municipality from which they got buffered and selected.

Comment: Did you buffer the fire or the municipalities? Also did you keep the buffer as a layer ?

Comment: Let me try to reframe the question: Do you want to find the nearest municipality for each forest fire polygon?

Comment: Try the "Join attributes by location" tool from the Processing Toolbox.

Comment: Hello; thanks for the answers.

Yes, I buffered the municipalties, and I want to add the name of the municipality from which the buffer originates to each and every polygone selected within its radius, as a new variable.

I will try "Join attributes by location".